# Duplicate the contents of the database column to another column using PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a site that holds many posts in the database. Currently, my table structure looks like this:

```
|-------|-------|-------------------|
|   id  |   url |   title           |
|-------|-------|-------------------|
|   1   |       |   Hello World     |
|   2   |       |   Hello World's   |
|   3   |       |   Hello & World   |
|-------|-------|-------------------|
```

In the table above looks empty `url` column. Yes, that column I just added, so there is nothing there. While in the `title` column, there are different post titles.

I have a problem with the `title` field, because there are some unsupported characters for the URL structure.
For example `http://google.com/?url=Hello World's`
So does the string `&` does not work there.

I plan to add a new column to serve as the url address. So like this my new table will be:

```
|-------|-------------------|-------------------|
|   id  |       url         |   title           |
|-------|-------------------|-------------------|
|   1   |   hello_world     |   Hello World     |
|   2   |   hello_worlds    |   Hello World's   |
|   3   |   hello_and_world |   Hello & World   |
|-------|-------------------|-------------------|
```

The addition of this `url` can be done manually via PHPMyAdmin, but my list of posts there are thousands of them. It is impossible to do it one by one. Is there an instant way to duplicate all data in the column `title` to the `url` column using PHP script and `change (spaces) to (_)`, `remove quotes`, and `change the sign (&) to (and)`?

Please do not give me advice to use `ID` as url address `?url=1, ?url=2, ?url=3`, because I want to use `title` as my post address. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a bunch of replaces.  You can do:

```
update t
    set url = replace(replace(replace(title, ' ', '_'), '&', 'and'), '''', '');
```

Comment: Thanks, I try first

Comment: Successful. Thank you very much